# NameError returned with Python raw_input prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

I'm trying to create a for loop that prompts the user for a hobby 3 times, then appends each one to hobbies.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
hobbies = []

for tries in range(3):
    hobby = raw_input(input("what's your favorite hobby?: "))
    hobbies.append(hobby)
```

After I enter a response at the user input prompt, let's say for example my response is "competitive eating", I get the following error in Terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hobbyprompt.py", line 12, in <module>
    hobby = raw_input(input("what's your favorite hobby?: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'competitive eating' is not defined
```

I'm sure I'm making a really stupid mistake here, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: why are you using input inside raw_input anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input)`. It's completely redundant in your example. Just drop it and keep the `raw_input` only:

```
hobby = raw_input("what's your favorite hobby?: ")
```

EDIT:
To answer the question in the comments, `input` takes the string and attempts to evaluate it as a python expression (see [`eval`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) for details). Since "competitive eating" is not variable you've already defined, it cannot be evaluated, and hence the `NameError`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I know it's an error on my part but can you explain why, if you have    raw_input(input("what's your favorite hobby?: "))  it gives the NameError ? What's the erroneous logic that I created there?

Comment: @ChrisPurrone see my edited answer with the details.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the edited explanation! So basically, by inserting "input" into the statement it's checking to see if the user input matches a pre-defined string?

Answer (score 1):

You only need `raw_input`, not `input` followed by `raw_input`. Use

```
hobby = raw_input("what's your favorite hobby?: ")
```

In python 3.x, `input` does what `raw_input` did in previous versions. But prior to Python 3, `input`, in addition to reading a line from stdin, evaluated that line as if it were a valid Python expression. `raw_input` is the alternative, so you should use one or the other-- not both. Here, `raw_input` is appropriate.